# LINQ query returning duplicate rows when a left join is performed and more than one match is found with right table

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I am writing a C# LINQ to perform a left join as below

```
    from pt in context.PD
    join label in context.Labels on new { pt.LabelId, pt.SubLabelId } equals
    new { label .LabelId, label.SubLabelId } 
    into clientLabel 
    from status in clientLabel 
    select new LabelDto{
    LastStatus = pt.dubs> 0? 
    clientLabel.FirstOrDefault(s => s.type== 1).Label 
   : clientLabel.FirstOrDefault(s => s.type== 2).Label
     LastSubStatus = pt.dubs> 0 ? 
     clientLabel.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.type==1).SubLabel
   : clientLabel.FirstOrDefault(s => s.type== 2).SubLabel
    };
```

right table(`Labels`) may have more than one matching rows in which case row to be returned will be selected based on `type(1 or 2)` but the above query returns duplicate row one with `type = 1` and other with `type = 2` where I want only one row either `type = 1 or 2`

**What do I change to get the desired output?**

Comment: Do a .`ToLookup()` projection, then collate the first element of the resulting projection into a common list using `.SelectMany()`.

Comment: Keep the `GroupJoin` by removing `from status in clientLabel` line.

Comment: You aren't doing a left join since you have `from status in clientLabel` and not `from status in clientLabel.DefaultIfEmpty()`.